# How do you disable an img in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an `img` that has an attribute directive that handles click events. I want to be able to `disable` and `enable` the handler. How do I do that?

**JS**

```
.directive('choose', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            el.on('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    // stuff
                    // disable el
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
.controller('QuizCtrl', function ($scope, Quiz, $routeParams) {
    this.next = function() {
        // enable ALL els
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img choose />
<button ng-click="q.next()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using css also:

JS

```
.directive('choose', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            el.on('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {});
            });
            scope.enable = function(){
                el.css({pointerEvents: ''});
            };
            scope.disable = function(){
                el.css({pointerEvents: 'none'});
            };
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing an overlay on the image after image have been clicked

HTML

```
<div ng-if='disablerToggle' class='disabler'>
    <img choose />
    <button ng-click="q.next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.disabler
{
    width:fitToImageButton;
    height:fitToImageButton;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Angular Controller

```
.controller('QuizCtrl', function ($scope, Quiz, $routeParams) {
    this.next = function() {
        $scope.disablerToggle = true;
        // enable ALL els
    };
});
```

Hope I helped!